# Initializing Variable Through Function

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I'm learning pointers and references but I'm having trouble grasping the concept. I need to declare a variable in my main function and then have it initialized through a function by user input, without returning anything. I've tried:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void input(int &num){
   cout << "Enter A Number" << endl;
   cin >> static_cast<int>(num);
}
int main(){
   int x;
   input(x);
   cout << "The Number You Entered Was " << x << "!" << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it correctly, except for that `static_cast<int>` there. What is it doing there? What made you use that cast?

Get rid of that cast, and it should work. This

```
cin >> num;
```

is all you need.

**P.S.** Just keep in mind that in C++ terminology the term *initialize* has very specific meaning. Formally, *initialization* is always a part of variable *definition*. Whatever changes you do to that variable after the definition is no longer *initialization*. In your case variable `x` is declared without an initializer, which means that it begins its life *uninitialized* (with indeterminate value). Later you put some specific value into `x` by reading it from `cin`, but this is no longer *initialization* (in C++ meaning of the term).

It might be a good idea to declare your `x` with some determinate initial value, like

```
int x = 0;
```

although personally I'm not a big fan of "dummy" initializers.

Comment: @Derp: String? What string? Where did "string" come from?

Comment: I just figured that you would be reading in a string, even though it is a number. Like if the user would type "one". Anyway I'm getting uninitialized local variable x?

Comment: @Derp `std::cin`s operator<<` has many overloads, one of those takes an integer. See my answer.

Comment: cin >> num is equivalent cin.operator>>(int& num). As you can see, the type there is int, not a string.

Comment: @Derp: What exactly do you mean by "getting uninitialized local variable x"?

Comment: @Derp: It does read a sequence of characters (user's input), which is interpreted as a number (not `one` though, but rather `12345` etc.), converted to type `int` and stored in your variable `num`. If the user enters `123`, variable `num` receives value `123`.

Answer (score 1):

You should drop the `static_cast`.

```
cin >> num;
```

[std::cin's operator>>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) has overloads that take integral types.

Note that you are not initializing a variable through a function at all. You are assigning a value to a variable by passing a reference to it to a function.

Answer (score 0):

No need for the `static_cast` stuff. Your function is given a *reference* to an `int`, and you want to read an `int`. Since you've passed a reference to the variable, the changes to it in your `input` function will be reflected in the caller.